# ¿Como exportar graficas de Matplotlib con Reportlab?

Tags: python, tkinter, reportlab

Estoy creando una interfaz grafica, con python y el modulo tkinter, la interfaz me tiene que generar una grafica y si pulso el boton exportar me la tiene que generar en un pdf con la libreria **Reportlab** ¿Como la exporto?

```
import matplotlib, sys
 matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from numpy import arange, sin, pi, cos
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, 
NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
import matplotlib as pl
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np


master = tk.Tk()
master.title("Exportadora")
master.geometry("800x700")


cv = tk.Frame(master, width=400, height=400)
cv.grid(row=0,column=1)

def graficar():
        grafica= fig.gca()
        t = arange(0.0,3.0,0.01)
        Fun1 = sin(2*pi*t)
        grafica.plot(t,Fun1)
        dataPlot.draw()

btnGrafica= tk.Button(master, text='graficar', command=graficar)
btnGrafica.grid(row=1,column=0)

btnExportar= tk.Button(master, text='Exportar')
btnExportar.grid(row=1,column=1)


fig = Figure(figsize=(6,6), dpi=100)
dataPlot = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=cv)
dataPlot.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
master.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La opción más simple es que generes una imagen de la gráfica usando [`matplotlib.pytplot.savefig`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html) y posteriormente solo tienes que proceder como con cualquier imagen con `reportlab.lib.utils.ImageReader` y `canvas.drawImage`:

```
import io
import sys
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
import matplotlib as pl
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.utils import ImageReader       


master = tk.Tk()
master.title("Exportadora")
master.geometry("800x700")


cv = tk.Frame(master, width=400, height=400)
cv.grid(row=0,column=1)
fig = Figure(figsize=(6, 6), dpi=100)


def graficar():
    grafica= fig.gca()
    t = np.arange(0.0, 3.0, 0.01)
    Fun1 = np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)
    grafica.plot(t, Fun1)
    dataPlot.draw()

def exportar():
    data = io.BytesIO()
    fig.savefig(data, format='png')
    data.seek(0)

    c = canvas.Canvas("reporte.pdf")
    Image = ImageReader(data)
    c.drawImage(Image, 45, 171, width=500, height=500)
    c.save()

btnGrafica= tk.Button(master, text='graficar', command=graficar)
btnGrafica.grid(row=1,column=0)

btnExportar= tk.Button(master, text='Exportar', command=exportar)
btnExportar.grid(row=1,column=1)


dataPlot = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=cv)
dataPlot.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
master.mainloop()
```

Esto es solo un ejemplo básico basado en tu código, te crea un pdf en el directorio de trabajo de tu script llamado *reporte.pdf* con tamaño de página por defecto (595.27 x 841.89 puntos, A4) con la imagen de la gráfica (500 x 500 pixeles) aproximadamente centrada.

Para no crear la imagen en disco se usa [`io.BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) para simular un archivo en modo binario temporal.

> Documentación de ReportLab:  https://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf

Comment: Muchas gracias @FJSevilla.
Bendiciones